# WebServiceSampler: error in Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I use jmeter 2.8.
I have sent request using HTTP Request Sampler. I have sent 10 http requests. I have parsed the response using XPath Extractor and stored value in variable.

I have replaced that value in the next http request using Beanshell Preprocessor.
I have used following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;
WebServiceSampler wsSampler = (WebServiceSampler) sampler;
String requestWithCertif = wsSampler.getXmlData().replaceFirst("#variable to replace#", vars.get("${replacevalue}"));
wsSampler.setXmlData(requestWithCertif);
```

But the following error has been occurred.
I have followed this [link](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/webservice-testing-with-jmeter-passing-data-from-a-response-to-another-request/) for how parse the response:

> ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;
>   WebServiceSamp . . . '' : Typed variable declaration

I hope the error seems to be variable declaration about this line

String requestWithCertif = wsSampler.getXmlData().replaceFirst("#variable to replace#", vars.get("${replacevalue}"));

can someone explain me how to use variable declaration in this beanshell script?

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Use HTTP Sampler with Raw Post Body and put your XML with variables inside ${} in the body.

WebserviceSampler will be deprecated in up coming 2.9 version.

Comment: yes.I already did the same as you told like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Envelope xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/
    documents/Message">
      <Body>
      ${variable}
    </Body>
</Envelope>
I have put the xml in HTTP sampler in Post body.but i need to replace this variable in next HTTP sampler.that s i'm using BeanShell preprocessor with above code.

Comment: I have attached for screen short for HTTP plan.

Comment: I wanted the whole test plan, also please explain again what you want to do with an example by ediing the question. I must say I don't understand what you want to do anymore

Comment: I have edited the question.but you said removed ) this part.I think that is not suitable.because need to two )) for at end of the code.see the code.

Comment: I don't see any image in answer, maybe there was an error in upload